# Execute chunks of code in order batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script who executes every command line by line (without jumping over executable or compiling processes then comes back to them).
I tried using `start /wait` command before executables/compile commands but it doesn't work either.

I want something like

> execute all lines from chunk1 THEN continue to chunk2

and so on.
E.g.

```
::Compile every source individually
for %%i in ( *.c ) do (
     gcc -pipe -O2 -c -x c "%%i"
)
::Get the number of .o files from the dir listing
for /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('dir *.o^|find "File(s)"') do set o_files=%%A
:: Build a string with all of the .o files (up to 512 due to string length limitations)
for /L %%A in (1,1,!o_files!) do set "o_string=!o_string! compile_to_c%%A.o"

gcc -Xlinker -no-as-needed !o_string! -x none -o compile_to_c
:: Clean the directory

del *.o*
strip compile_to_c.exe
mkdir T1
move /y compile_to_c.exe T1 >nul
cd T1
start /wait compile_to_c.exe -verbose -boost -no_gc compile_to_c -o compile_to_c.new
cd ..
::mkdir T2
move /y T1\* T2 >nul
move /y T2\compile_to_c.exe T1 >nul
```

(The program listed above compiles all the c sources from the current directory, combines them into an exe, moves the exe into another folder and  then executes it (the exe))

Comment: batch scripts do exactly that. Your question is unclear without you showing what *actually* goes wrong in an **Minimal, Verifiable Example**

Comment: @MarcusMüller done. hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, I'm not an expert in windows programming, but what you have here is a poor man's Makefile. Look into using a real Makefile instead! That way, you'll even get functionality like "only recompile files that have changed", automatically.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this is just a snippet from a big batch file ,and makefile is not a solution for this case.But thanks anyway.

Comment: well, using `make` / a Makefile for the first part definitely would make sense. But design choices are yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, batch files are executed sequentially and synchronously. In other words, each command is executed and the system waits for it to complete before moving on to the next one.

But you can also jump forward and back inside a batch file (GOTO), and you can execute specific sections in the order you want (CALL). If you don't explicitly use those commands, the batch will execute in the order it is written.

So for instance, consider the following:

```
@echo off

Echo Line 1
Echo Line 2
Echo Line 3
Echo Line 4
Echo Line 5
```

This will produce the expected output, in the order listed:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

You can change the order of execution by placing labels (i.e. lines that start with : ) inside the batch file and referring to those markers with the CALL statement in order to execute only the commands *below* that marker:

```
@echo off
call :Line3
call :Line5

:Line1
Echo Line 1
Echo Line 2
goto :eof

:Line3
Echo Line 3
Echo Line 4
goto :eof

:Line5
Echo Line 5
goto :eof
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 1
Line 2
```

As you can see, at the end of each section a special **goto :eof** instruction tells the script to stop processing any further command and return control to the statement immediately following the CALL that initiated the jump.
Now you may wonder why the *Line 1* and *Line 2* statements are still displayed even though you never explicitly called them. That's because after the *CALL :Line5* statement is completed, the next statements are executed anyway since, as I stated at the beginning, the batch file always executes statements sequentially by default. And those statements that follow happen to be the ones that display *Line 1* and *Line 2*.

So there you have it: you now know how to execute all commands in a certain section and THEN commands in another section, in the order you want.